# Oracle sql - all records deleted and cannot retrieve data

Tags: oracle

All records from all of my tables were removed from database. I didn't use any DELETE method to clear the database. Have you got any idea what could happen? I have never had similar situation before.
I tried to retrieve data by following command

```
  select * from matches as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '24' hour;
```

but I get error: 01555. 00000 -  "snapshot too old: rollback segment number %s with name "%s" too small"

I only add/update records and have no idea how to retrieve data from my tables.

Can someone guide me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

ORA1555 might be caused by **another** process in the database. The root cause is often that someone commits inside of a pl/SQL loop. It is a classic mistake to commit every 1000 rows or do while processing a large table

Tom Kyte of Oracle database fame describes the problem [in this AskTom Question clearly](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1441804355350) The main point is:

> An ORA-1555 is never about running out of rollback. It is about
> rollback that was generated being overwritten. A select statement will
> not cause rollback to be "held". As soon as the transaction that
> generated the rollback commits - that rollback may be reused and if it
> is and it is needed by some query, you will get an ORA-1555.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your data was almost certainly *not* deleted. Don't use `as of` in your query. The system is trying to retrieve data as it existed at that moment in time `systimestamp - interval '24'`, which might even be before the inserts, and which you no longer have enough `redo` to do, regardless. Just use:

```
select * from matches;
```

Comment: Of course I used 
`select * from matches;` query but it didn't return any result. The only option to display results was running query from the post. But now, I am not even able to run this query due to 
`01555. 00000 -  "snapshot too old: rollback segment number %s with name \"%s\" too small"
*Cause:    rollback records needed by a reader for consistent read are
          overwritten by other writers
*Action:   If in Automatic Undo Management mode, increase undo_retention setting. Otherwise, use larger rollback segments
`
I tried to restore system to 2 days ago, but didn't help as well

Comment: A more detailed explanation of what state your system was in, how the data was inserted, what worked at that point, and a timeline of *everything* you've tried to recover the data would be helpful. Was this data present/available for a long time already, or was it just inserted and then disappeared right away? What sort of backup/restore was attempted? Why didn't that work? Do you have any auditing enabled? Exactly what other commands (that you know of) *were* run against your tables? What kind of environment are you working in (dev, test, prod) and what version of Oracle?

Comment: It happened for me for the first time and I have saved records to database since ~ 1 year. The only commands I use  only SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE. Few days ago I used database and everything was fine, but the next day all records were removed. I use the database only for my own purposes.  I am just looking for  solution to retrieve data from the past - I tried something like `insert into matches (select * from matches as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '24' hour) ` but it didn't work. I use Oracle SQL developer environment. Is maybe any way in this tool to restore data?

Comment: Without more detail, the only thing I can question is whether you finalized the missing transactions with the `COMMIT` command. If not, then they may have been rolled back - effectively undone - when you logged out. If they *were* committed, then at this point there likely isn't anything you can do without a good RMAN backup to restore from and unless you're willing to lose the data you've added since then. The ORA-01555 error indicates that you're already past the point where a flashback query is possible, assuming the inserts were committed correctly in the first place.